# Python: DataFrame.melt - How to select a range of columns as the identifier variables?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I'm trying to change the structure of my dataset

Currently have:

```
RE id    Country    0    1   2    ...    n
1001     CN,TH     CN   TH   nan  ...    nan
1002     UK        UK   nan  nan  ...    nan
```

I've split the Country column out, hence the additional columns. Now I am trying to use df.melt to get this:

```
RE id    var  val 
1001      0   CN 
1001      0   TH
```

So I can eventually get to this by using a pivot

```
RE id     Country
1001      TH
1001      CN
```

I've tried:

```
df = a.melt(id_vars=[a[[0]],a[[1]],a[[2]]], value_vars=['RE id'])
```

How can I select the range of columns in my dataframe to use as the identifer variables?
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was that you were referencing the column names incorrectly. Also, I believe you had `id_vars` (should be `Re id`, I think) and `value_vars` (column names `0` and `1`) inverted in your code.

Here is how I approached this

Imports

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Here is a part of the data, sufficient to demonstrate the likely problem

```
a = [['Re id', 0, 1],[1001,'CN','TH'],[1002,'UK',np.nan]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a[1:], columns=a[0])
print(df)

    Re id    0    1
0    1001   CN   TH
1    1002   UK  NaN
```

Now, use `pd.melt` with

1. `id_vars` pointing to `Re id`
2. `value_vars` as the 2 columns you want to `melt` (namely, column names `0` and `1`)

```
df_melt = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Re id'], value_vars=[0,1], value_name='Country')
df_melt.sort_values(by=['Re id', 'Country'], ascending=[True,False], inplace=True)
print(df_melt)
    Re id   variable    Country
2    1001          1         TH
0    1001          0         CN
1    1002          0         UK
3    1002          1        NaN
```

Also, since you have the `Country` names in separate columns (`0`,`1`), I do not think that you need to use the `Country` column at all.

Comment: you are using an array of columns, but not a range. Is that possible too? I have tried `value_vars=[0:1]`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @AxelKöhler, you would need to use `range` to specify the range of column names that you require. So, if you wanted to use column **names** `[0,1,2,...,8,9]`, then you could use `value_vars=list(range(0,10))`, where `list(range(0,10))` corresponds to column names. If you wanted to use a range of column **indexes** `0,1,2,...,8,9`, then you would need to use `value_vars=df.columns.tolist()[0:10]`, where `df.columns.tolist()[0:10]` corresponds to column names.

Comment: Okay, and what if the application expects these column names as strings? 

Comment: Never mind, this will do:
`[str(x) for x in range(1961,2014)]`